# How to determine correct location of image/file

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit confused and hoping someone can help me figure this out, I have my project folder with a couple folders JS, Images, and CSS. My click event and function worked in Linux both now it is not working on Windows. The image location should be "../images/imagename.png" but it will only work with "./images/imagename.png" in Windows.[image]

Trying to figure out why ../path is not working when it should be the correct path. Even when it shows the path it will not work. But leaving ./path does.
[image]

Comment: `../` means go up one folder and `./` means the current folder

Comment: When running from the IDE, Visual Studio defines the working directory one level up (possibly the project directory) by default.

Comment: I'm working in the JS folder, shouldn't I need to go up one folder and then access the image folder with ../? ./ would mean I'm still in the JS folder but that's not where the images are located.